# If the probability density function is equal to $mx+b$ for $0<x<5$, and $0$ other wise, what is the probability of $x=1$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

The pdf is $$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            mx+b & \quad 0<x<5 \\
            0 & \quad \text {otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

The question is:

> What is P(X=1)?

In my textbook, it says $P(X=1)=F(1)-F(1^-)$. F is the cumulative density function CDF.

My answer:$$P(X=1)=\int^1_0 (mx+b) dx-\int^{1^-}_0 (mx+b) dx$$

Is this zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a continuous random variable, then by definition $$P(X=1)=0$$

In general, the probability that a continuous random variable takes a specific value $a$ is $0$, because

$$P(X=a) = \int_{\{a\}}f_X\,d\lambda = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

The probability of a continuous variable taking a particular value is 0.

[Why is the probability of a continuous variable taking a particular value zero? Explain only logically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206409/why-is-the-probability-of-a-continuous-variable-taking-a-particular-value-zero)