# Choosing a number in 0 to 1

Tags: real-numbers

I can pick a number in the interval from all real numbers from 0 to 1. Say this number is 0.42. Now the probability for drawing this number most be zero since we have infinity many numbers in the interval 0 to 1. Is this true and is it not a paradox ?

Comment: This is true, and no, it is not a paradox. It's only a paradox if you think that "with probability $0$" and "impossible" mean the same thing. They don't.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180283/why-is-the-probability-that-a-continuous-random-variable-takes-a-specific-value/180301#180301

Comment: I've heard of this referred to as the [paradox of the dartboard (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDl7g_2x74Q)

Comment: In the standard sense,it is zero. If you want to consider things in a "standard" and "uniform" way, you can consider the Lebesgue measure, which is a uniform measure over the Borel σ-algebra with the usual meaning of length, area or volume, depending on dimension.For example, for R the Lebesgue measure of the interval (a,b) is (b−a). Now the rationals have Lebesgue measure zero, hence the fact.

Comment: A probability is always something depending of the $\sigma$-algebra of events so it can change according this last definition.

Answer (score 0):

If we could have a real way to pick a random number between 0 and 1, which would be extremely difficult, there would be a infinitely small (infinitesimal) chance of picking each number.